# Vowpal Wabbit multiclass (csoaa) classification always returns max label, even for training data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to get a simple multiclass classification to work using Vowpal Wabbit, but despite reading every available example and stackoverflow posts, it just won't work correctly. 
This is what my training file train.vw looks like [about 60k lines, with even distribution of class examples]:

```
1:0.0 2:1.0 3:1.0 4:1.0 5:1.0 6:1.0 7:1.0 8:1.0 9:1.0 ex1|f 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 ... 100:0
```

This is what my test file test.vw looks like [>100k examples]:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ex1|f 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 ... 100:0
```

I use *csoaa*, so I invoke training like this:

```
vw -d train.vw --csoaa 9 -f data.model -p train.pred
```

The train.pred contains correctly labelled examples.

Then I test like this:

```
vw -t -i data.model train.vw -p train.predict -r train.raw
```

And interestingly, train.predict contains

```
9.000000 ex1
9.000000 ex2
9.000000 ex3  [etc]
```

Same happens when testing on test.vw.

If you look at train.raw, you indeed see that label 9 always has the highest probability by far:

```
1:4.466 2:2.54384 3:2.00479 4:1.4716 5:5.43068 6:4.33557 7:0.725791     8:4.04874 9:-2.10407 ex1
1:6.74119 2:3.91698 3:5.75727 4:3.05082 5:5.17448 6:2.04901 7:3.54167     8:2.57396 9:-2.72631 ex2
```

My question is: Why does this happen, and what do I need to do to make sure that test examples are assigned reasonable labels?

I have seen a lot of people having similar problems, but it usually boiled down to using an incorrect input format.

I am using Vowpal Wabbit v7.10.1.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Chris

Comment: Have you tried to shuffle (random order) the training examples? If the end of train.vw contains examples with correct (cost=0) label 9 then it is no surprise that the model predicts 9 everywhere. This is online learning.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, that solves it. Makes perfect sense! :)